# wordpress plugin admin panel creation

Tags: wordpress, plugins, admin, manual

I'm looking for a good manual/help page to create an nice admin panel for a wordpress plugin.

I have created the basic admin panel and the plugin, but where I run into, is the problem that I want to allow my users to edit information which is stored in the plugin related database tables.

The basis is that there is a list of all items in the database, which a user can click to edit. I'm able to let users edit it, but one an error (not a correct id number as example) or on cancellation, the redirect to the original list is the first point I'm running into.

Before asking all these questions related to the admin panel, I was wondering if there are any good websites with helpguides/manuals to help building these kind of plugins.

With kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you google it?  Search for wordpress options panels.

[KC Settings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kc-settings/) is amazing as you can create all the options with a nice interface, then just plugin the code to your templates where needed.

Off the top of my head,  [Jaredatch metaboxes](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress), Options Tree, WP Alchemy.  Personally, I like KC Settings and Jaretach metaboxes, but there's a host of them out there each with their strengths.  KC Settings ease of use, jeradatch great veriaty of input options (wysiwyg, sliders, checkboxes, email, times, etc), WP Alchemy with quality OOP and documentation, etc.

Hope that helps.